# Cannot write to dsPIC30F OSCCON

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, pic

My current project needs to have the dsPIC30F go into low power mode when it receives an external "low power warning" signal. I've verified that `EnterLowPowerMode()` does in fact execute. However, when I try to adjust the `OSCCON` postscalar with both the built in `__builtin_write_OSCCONL()` and with `asm()` embedded in the C code, the value of `OSCCON<7:6>` remains the same.

I don't understand why the assembly isn't working. It seems straightforward, enough.

```
void EnterLowPowerMode()
{
uint8_t writeUnlock1 = 0x46;
uint8_t writeUnlock2 = 0x57;
uint8_t writeData = 0xC0;
// Set PMD1 and PMD2 equal to 0xFFFF
*PMD1 = 0xFFFF; // Disable peripherals in Peripheral Module Disable register 1
*PMD2 = 0xFFFF; // Disable peripherals in Peripheral Module Disable register 2

// Unlock OSCCON and set OSCCON<7:6> to b11
// OSCCON address is 0x0742
__builtin_write_OSCCONL(0xC0);
//    asm("MOV.w #0x0742,w0");
//    asm("MOV.w #0x46,w1");
//    asm("MOV.w #0x57,w2");
//    asm("mov.w #0xC0,w3");
//    asm("disi #3");
//    asm("mov.b w1,[w0]");
//    asm("mov.b w2,[w0]");
//    asm("mov.b w3,[w0]");

// Set bit 15 of T1CON equal to 0
*T1CON = *T1CON & 0x7FFF;

// Set T1MR equal to 0x0000
*T1MR = 0x0000;

// Set T1PR equal to 0x00FA
*T1PR = 0x00FA;

// Set T1CON equal to 0x8000
*T1CON = 0x8000;

// Set gInLowPowerMode to kcg_true
gInLowPowerMode = kcg_true;

while(gLowPowerTime < C_LOW_POWER_TIMEOUT)
{
    // wait
}

// repeat OSCCON unlock process here

// Set bits 6-7 of OSCCON to b00
*OSCCON = *OSCCON & 0xFF3F;

// Set bit 15 of T1CON to 0
*T1CON = *T1CON & 0x7FFF;

// Set T1MR to 0x0000
*T1MR = 0x0000;

// Set T1PR equal to 0x07D0
*T1PR = 0x07D0;

// Set T1CON equal to 0x8010
*T1CON = 0x8010;

// Set PMD1 equal to 0x81FC
*PMD1 = 0x81FC;

// Set PMD2 equal to 0xFFF9
*PMD2 = 0xFFF9;

// set SHORT_POWER_INTERRUPT to kcg_true
SHORT_POWER_INTERRUPT = kcg_true;

// set gInLowPowerMode to kcg_false
gInLowPowerMode = kcg_false;

}// end EnterLowPowerMode()
```

gLowPowerTime is incremented in an interrupt that's dependent upon the new, slower clock that should be set with the OSCCON postscalar, but since it's running too fast, the interrupt isn't interrupting.

**I've also tried putting all lines of assembly in a single asm(); statement, and that still didn't work.**

If I'm missing anything, let me know and I can update this fairly quickly.

Comment: Do you have a debugger?  Can you write those bits directly?  Why are you using `*OSCCON = *OSCCON & 0xFF3F;` later on?

Comment: Currently using the ICD3.


Documentation has shown that the bits can be written to, directly; however, Microchip's datasheet lacks any information on HOW to write the data. They have sample code, which I have attempted replicating for this application, and even that did not work.

And, the `*OSCCON = *OSCCON & 0xFF3F` was old code I have yet to update. For the time being, I've been focusing on setting the Postscalar value, but that's a good catch. Thanks.

Comment: So, one of my coworkers (and the Lead SW Engineer for this project) mentioned that the issue may be that there's a blend of C and Assembly in the function, and possibly breaking out the `asm()` statement to a different function may enable this to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe.  Did you look at the disassembly from what you have there?

Comment: @CarlNorum - I checked the disassembly, and as soon as I did, OSCCON began to accept the unlock command and the new bits. Go figure. But, I discovered that the timer interrupt isn't interrupting, so we're going into the other control registers to see if that is altering how they're running.

Comment: I should mention this: you can't just "step through" the assembly code, as it appears the debugger will insert commands. The reason why this suddenly started working was because I'd put the breakpoint after the `asm()` statements.

Answer (score 1):

```
__builtin_write_OSCCONL(0xC0);
```

This line just attempts to write 0xC0 to the lower byte of the OSCCON register. This will fail because there is a specific sequence that must be followed to manipulate bits in this register. It is outlined in section 7.4.1 of the [dsPIC30F reference manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70046E.pdf). I believe your mistake here was assuming that __builtin_write_OSCCONL was performing this sequence for you.

You want

```
__builtin_write_OSCCONL(0x46);
__builtin_write_OSCCONL(0x57);
__builtin_write_OSCCONL(0xC0);
//now the lower 8 bits of OSCCON should be 0xC0
```